# PHP code generates a segmentation fault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

Edit added.

I am getting a segmentation fault from the PHP ternary operation. I'm using PHP (5.4.13).

```
<?php

$t = empty($_GET['t2']) ? $_GET['t2'] : 'test';
$t = empty($_GET['t2']) ? 'test' : $_GET['t2'];

echo '<pre>'.print_r($t, true).'</pre>';

?>
```

The statements:

```
$t = empty($_GET['t2']) ? $_GET['t2'] : 'test';
$t = empty($_GET['t2']) ? 'test' : $_GET['t2'];
```

Dispatches a segmentation fault (I checked the apache error log for this).  The commented statements above do not throw the segmentation fault.

I doubt this is the only source error, but this is what I was able to narrow down. Almost all sites that use this php are now having this problem.

I don't think this is a bug! More an error in php installation or in one of the dependencies. But as no `function` was used, only language features, I thought it could be narrowed down pretty easily.

**EDIT:** 
I wanted to know what are the common problems that causes a segmentation fault, and if one of them can be identified from the above code so that I will know where to look for solutions and how to act. (this is the question, for those who wonder about it)

**EDIT 2:**
Ready now, there is no more assignment in $_GET, so I guess now it is `advisable` and valid. But the error is still there.

EDIT 3:
for valgrind, the trace is:

```
==3775== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3775==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==3775==    at 0x0: ???
==3775==    by 0xF60F9F7: execute (in /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==3775==    by 0xF5A619F: zend_execute_scripts (in /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==3775==    by 0xF548E87: php_execute_script (in /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==3775==    by 0xF650A94: ??? (in /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==3775==    by 0x133BAF: ap_run_handler (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x13746D: ap_invoke_handler (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x142B2F: ap_process_request (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x13F9A7: ??? (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x13B6B7: ap_run_process_connection (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x147976: ??? (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
==3775==    by 0x147C45: ??? (in /usr/sbin/httpd)
```

and for gdb is:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fc4dd8a49f8 in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp54-php5.so
#2  0x00007fc4dd83b1a0 in zend_execute_scripts () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp54-php5.so
#3  0x00007fc4dd7dde88 in php_execute_script () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp54-php5.so
#4  0x00007fc4dd8e5a95 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp54-php5.so
#5  0x00007fc4e818dbb0 in ap_run_handler ()
#6  0x00007fc4e819146e in ap_invoke_handler ()
#7  0x00007fc4e819cb30 in ap_process_request ()
#8  0x00007fc4e81999a8 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fc4e81956b8 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#10 0x00007fc4e81a1977 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fc4e81a1c46 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fc4e81a2293 in ap_mpm_run ()
#13 0x00007fc4e8179900 in main ()
```

**Final Edit**

As I suspected from the beginning it surely was from a corrupted installation of php and it's extensions. The code itself had no problem but I guess it used some part of the faulty installation. More can be added but as I did not found the exact cause and it's solution, but managing to make it work again, I thank you all for guiding me to a resolution.

Comment: I don't think setting values in `$_GET` is considered a good practice. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: What is @Aquillo says is true. If this is a bug, you are better off reporting to to the php bug database.

Comment: I ran this and no segfault for me. However, if t2 isn't defined, i do get an error for Undefined index: t2. But setting get values as said above isn't good practice

Comment: @datasage I don't know if this is a bug, this is why I am here. And it doesn't matter if this is a good practice or not, I can replace that `$_GET['t1']` with something like `$t1` and will still dispatch the error.

Comment: I don't think it's PHP version (checked http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and works)...

Comment: In java, if you mix datatypes in the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the ternary operator, there can be undefined behavior.  Perhaps PHP is suffering from a similar problem.  If you take out the ternary operator does it fix the segfault?  Use an if statement.  If that fixes your problem, then the problem is datatype mixing in the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the ternary operator.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: PHP does not have types as such the way Java does (not explicitely typed, though implicitely, they exist). The error is most likely a notice and not a segfault - at least, it does not segfault on all the servers I tried. You get a notice for undefined index but that's it.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?  If you have a bug report, you should submit it to the PHP team; that's not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Do you have non-latest APC installed? it is known to produce segmentation faults, but I'm not sure under which circumstances. In addition, empty() is not a function, it's a language construct. Try using sizeof()

Comment: @periklis you might have a point in there, thank you for your hint, I will get into it now. Also, the empty construct works fine. It seems putting a `$_GET` as an operand to `?:` (the ternary operator) gives the segfault.

Comment: do you get segfault also when just accessing $_GET variables? what do you actually have in there?

Comment: @eis I don't really know, most of my applications are inoperable, and I just took a simple one and tested and then narrowed it down to that line. It can be many other problems, but I will be glad to solve this first.

Comment: you should test it to narrow this down.

Comment: Did you try the isset function instead of "empty"?

Comment: Crikey - isn't this what chat is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at your code I don't believe you have any errors.

With that said you mentioned that you are now having issues with many of your sites.  I am wondering if you are now getting hit by malicious bots that might be causing an error similar to what is on this [PHP Bug Report][1]https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59748.[1]:.

I would look at your logs and see if traffic has changed on those sites to start taking advantage of this issue.

Comment: Actually, it was half my fault in configuring the php installation and it's extensions.